# Java super classes, subclasses, and arrays. Inherit subclass methods not showing in array

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am having trouble getting an array to give me the setters and getters for subclasses in my program.

I have the main class `Person`, the subclass `SchoolEmployee`, and two subclasses that inherit fields from `SchoolEmployee` (which inherits fields from the `Person` class).

I created a test file to check if everything is working, but it seems to only be able to give me the methods for the `Person` class.

For example, I created an array:

```
Person[] schoolemployees = new Person[4];
```

Then, I proceeded to put values in the array using the constructors I made for each class:

```
schoolemployees[0] = new Teacher(FirstNameHere, SecondName, etc...);
schoolemployees[1] = new Teacher(FirstNameHere, SecondName, etc...);
schoolemployees[2] = new Office(FirstNameHere, SecondName, etc...);
schoolemployees[2] = new Office(FirstNameHere, SecondName, etc...);
```

My problem is, I am only able to set/get fields and call methods from within the `Person` class.

For example:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name for first name");
schoolemployees[1].setFirstName(input);
```

When I try to set/get fields or call methods from within the subclasses, they will not show up at all.

Could someone please provide some insight into why I am unable to see the inherited fields in the array? Thank you.

Comment: Inheritance means that `SchoolEmployee` will have all members on `Person`, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is typed as a `Person[]`. This means that the compiler knows that each element is a `Person` (or `null`). It has no way of knowing that `schoolemployees[1]` is a `Teacher`, so it will not let you access fields or methods other than the ones common for all `Person`.

1. If all `Person` should have a `setFirstName`, then you can declare an abstract (or even a concrete) method on Person for it.
2. If you are sure that the given array entry is a `Teacher` you can typecast: `Teacher t = (Teacher)schoolemployees[1];`. Then you can call teacher methods on `t`. But you will get an exception when this person turned out not to be a teacher.
3. Maybe you want to have your array be a `SchoolEmployee[]` instead (that class seems to have your methods).

Comment: Only way #3 would not work is if either `Office` or `Teacher` has a method the other doesn't, then OP would need to cast appropriately, as in #2. Great answer.

Comment: WOW thank you very much! I was able to call other methods from the subclasses using type-casting!

Answer (score 0):

I think about that your problem, there are one way. you can make the abstract class of person. and inherits the SchoolEmployee. you define same method that common your opinion for example setName(String str) because all object get the name. and you expand your function

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using reference of Person class So during compile time method call will be resolved from the Person class. e.g.

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    private String ClassName;

    public String getClassName() {
        return ClassName;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        ClassName = className;
    }
}
```

And you are accessing it in below way

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setFirstName("Naresh");
student.setClassName("Highschool");


// For compiler person is Person (at runtime it will be resolved to object of Student class), and person class doesn't have setClassName() defined in it compiler will give an error while accessing it
Person person = new Student();
person.setFirstName("Naresh");

// Compilation error here because setClassName() is not accessible from Person
person.setClassName("Highschool");
```